# Operador += do Java

Tags: java, operadores

Sempre achei que o operador `+=` funcionava apenas como uma forma mais curta para o incremento tradicional, por exemplo:

```java
i += j;
```

Ao invés de:

```java
i = i + j;
```

Mas ao realizar o seguinte experimento:

```java
int i = 3;
long j = 7;
```

Então, quando executo `i = i + j;` resulta em erro, enquanto  `i += j;` compila normalmente.

Diante disso, será que é possível afirmar que `i += j;` na verdade é semelhante a `i = (tipo do i) (i + j);`?

Comment: Só à caráter de curiosidade eu testei na linguagem `Objective-C` e funcionou a função que deu erro no seu código em  `Java`, vou pesquisar mais a fundo essa questão.

Comment: @iTSangar creio que o erro se encontra em misturar dois tipos de dados durante a operação, por isso a necessidade de um casting tipo: `i = (int) (i+j);`, eu acho...

Comment: Acho legal este tipo de pergunta porque desmistifica coisas que as pessoas aprendem errado intuitivamente. E intuição sem um conhecimento sólido do assunto mais prejudica do ajuda.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Isso é uma característica da linguagem. Como [explicado na documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), o uso de operadores do tipo op= inclui um *casting* implícito:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

[Fonte original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781069/implicit-conversion-in-java-operator) da resposta no SO em inglês.

Answer (score 14):

Gostaria de incrementar a resposta mostrando como [o compilador](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) avalia a expressão:

```
int i = 3;
long j = 7;     

 i += j;
```

A expressão acima se traduz pelo javac ([J2SE 8 = 52 - 0x34 hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)) em:

```
ILOAD 1: i  //obtem o inteiro de i
I2L         //converte o inteiro para long
LLOAD 2: j  //obtem o long de j
LADD        //soma os longs (i + j)
L2I         //converte o long para inteiro
ISTORE 1: i //guarda o inteiro em i
```

Sendo na prática:

```
i = (int) ((long) i + j);
```

Answer (score 7):

Quando você soma tipos primitivos  diferentes, onde um deles é maior que o outro(soma de long com int, ou double com int) é preciso fazer o cast. O erro de compilação é a JVM te informando que o resultado da soma de dois números que vai ser atribuída no int pode perder valor(Ex: somar 4.6287 com 1 e colocar dentro do int, vai ter apenas o número 5). Quando você faz o cast , você informa a JVM que está ciente disso e vai assumir os riscos.

Quando você usa i += j, na verdade é isso que a JVM faz: i = (int)(i + j);